# add mean value on boxplot with ggpubr

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, ggpubr

I'm trying to add a label on boxplot using ggpubr package. Here's the code I used:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
compare_means(len ~ supp, data = ToothGrowth, method="t.test", paired=TRUE, group.by = "dose")
# Box plot facetted by "dose"
p1 <- ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "supp", y = "len", xlab=F,
      color = "supp", palette = "jco",
      facet.by = "dose", add="mean", short.panel.labs = FALSE)
# Use only p as label.
p2 <- p1 + stat_compare_means(method = "t.test", paired = T,  label = "p")
p2
```

And the sample data (ToothGrowth)

```
15.5   VC  1.0
23.6   VC  2.0
18.5   VC  2.0
33.9   VC  2.0
25.5   VC  2.0
26.4   VC  2.0
32.5   VC  2.0
26.7   VC  2.0
21.5   VC  2.0
23.3   VC  2.0
29.5   VC  2.0
15.2   OJ  0.5
21.5   OJ  0.5
17.6   OJ  0.5
 9.7   OJ  0.5
14.5   OJ  0.5
10.0   OJ  0.5
 8.2   OJ  0.5
 9.4   OJ  0.5
16.5   OJ  0.5
 9.7   OJ  0.5
```

Is there any way to add a mean value as a text (other than the dot using : add="mean")

If possible, I'd like to place the mean value text right under the "p=0.000" which comes from the "stat_compare_means" code.

also, is there a way to remove the legend automatically generated when grouping the plot?

the final plot I want to make looks like this :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qudMy.png]

1. add the mean value as text on the boxplot
2. remove the legend at the top

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And where should the mean value be? At the median?

Comment: @erocoar below the p value would be nice but anywhere is fine

Comment: please revise your question and include some data and some code. I can't open the links.

Comment: @Jimbou I just revised the question. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
p1 + stat_compare_means(method = "t.test", paired = T,  label = "p", label.x = 0.8)+ 
     stat_summary(fun.data = function(x) data.frame(y=32, label = paste("Mean=",mean(x))), geom="text") +
     theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]